# how to bind Background and BorderBrush of border with label Background programmatically after creating them by code

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I created a border and a label by code in c# wpf
I want to create a data binding for `Background` and `BorderBrush` of border with
the `Background` of the label

Here is the code

```
void creatlbl()
{
    Border b = new Border();
    b.Name = "b11";
    b.Margin = new Thickness(300,17,0,419);
    b.Height = 32;
    b.CornerRadius = new CornerRadius(5);
    b.Width = 181;
    b.BorderThickness = new Thickness(2);
    b.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
    lgingrd.Children.Add(b); //
    Label l = new Label();
    l.Name = "l111";
    l.Content = "l111";
    l.Height = 28;
    l.Width = 177;
    l.Foreground = (Brush)bc.ConvertFrom("#FF346D80");
    l.FontSize = 20;
    l.Background = (Brush)bc.ConvertFrom("#FF9AB426");
    l.HorizontalContentAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
    l.Padding = new Thickness(0,0,0,0);
    l.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    b.Child = l;
    // here i want to set binding for border 
    // the  background and borderbrush of border equal to the background of label 
}
```

same thing i did for a button in XAML like that

```
<Border x:Name="brdbt" Margin="120,58,0,378"
    BorderBrush="{Binding Background, ElementName=bt}" <!--this is the binding which i want-->
    Height="32"
    CornerRadius="5"
    Width="181"
    BorderThickness="2"
    HorizontalAlignment="Left" Background="{Binding Background, ElementName=bt}">
    <Button x:Name="bt" Content="btntxt" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="28" Width="177" Click="bt_click" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Foreground="#FFE8EEF0" FontSize="20" Padding="1,-1,1,1" MouseEnter="bt_mcentr" MouseLeave="bt_mclv" Background="#FFE62828"/>
</Border>
```

Is there any way to do above xaml type binding in c# code for border and label I mentioned above in c# code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

create `Binding` object with path "Background" which uses label `l` as source (`new Binding("Background") { Source = l }`) and assign that binding to target properties: Border.Background and Border.BorderBrush

```
BindingOperations.SetBinding(b, BackgroundProperty,  new Binding("Background") { Source = l });
BindingOperations.SetBinding(b, BorderBrushProperty, new Binding("Background") { Source = l });
```

Answer (score -1):

You know it would be simpler to create this entire block of code in xaml.
Just wrap it in DataTemplate with key.
In your code, create a ContentPresenter, give it your data as content, 
And give it your DataTemplate as it's ContentTemplate value:

```
ContentPresenter cp = new ContentPresenter();
cp.Content = (?)
cp.ContentTemplate = Application.Current.Resources.Find("DataTemplateKey") as DataTemplate;
```